# MFC Statusbar - Making text a link with button behavior

Tags: c++, mfc, statusbar

I,m trying to use a status bar in an MFC application as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2289/Adding-a-status-bar-to-an-MFC-dialog).

I managed to add items to my status bar as described in the link.
There's nothing that I could post here as code reference as its currently 1:1 as in the link.

What I want is to make the text a link, so that when clicked, I'll catch this call-back and do something. I couldn't find how to do it, yet I've seen it in apps before.

Comment: It's been years since I've done anything with MFC but we used to insert a custom CStatic control that provided hyperlink functionality. Wasn't too hard actually.

Comment: How can it be done? Is there any kind of reference that explains it?

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar, but you need to derive your own class from `CStatusBar`.

---

a) place the following code at the top of your derived `StatusBar.cpp`

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyStatusBar, CStatusBar)
    ON_WM_LBUTTONUP()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

---

b) add the following declaration for `CMyStatusBar` in your derived `StatusBar.h`

```
afx_msg void OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
```

---

c) place the following code later on in your derived `StatusBar.cpp`

```
void CMyStatusBar::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{   CRect rc;
    int nPaneIndex = CommandToIndex(ID_INDICATOR_TIME);
    GetStatusBarCtrl().GetRect(nPaneIndex, &rc);
    if (rc.PtInRect(point))
    {   // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to write **OnLButtonUp** for the header declaration.